# How to apply read/write permissions to user-uploaded files in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, permissions

I have a "document" model, an upload system using dropzone.js and the register/login. Im now lost on how to apply permissions to each individual uploaded **File** so only the specified users can access them.

Basically:
File1->accessible_by = user1,user2

File2->accesible_by=user3,user5...

And so on.

Thanks to anyone for advice/help on my problem.

## Edit with relevant code:

### Create Document View:

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['file', 'is_public']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        data = {'status': 'success'}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype =
        response_mimetype(self.request))
        return response
```

I did the above to the view to handle dropzone.js file uploading.

### This is my "document" model

```
class Document(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'files/')
                                #validators=[validate_file_type])
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                related_name='uploadedByAsUser', null=True)

    allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                related_name='allowedUsersAsUser')

    def clean(self):
        self.file.seek(0)
        self.extension = self.file.name.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-1]
        if self.extension == 'xlsx' or self.extension == 'xls':
            self.thumbnail = 'xlsx.png'
        elif self.extension == 'pptx' or self.extension == 'ppt':
            self.thumbnail = 'pptx.png'
        elif self.extension == 'docx' or self.extension == 'doc':
            self.thumbnail = 'docx.png'


    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #delete file from /media/files
        self.file.delete(save = False)
        #call parent delete method.
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    #Redirect to file list page.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashby-files:files')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name.split('/')[-1]

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-uploaded_at']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `allowed_user` field into the document model, so that only those users specified can access the files. for example:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = FileField()
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploadedByAsUser')
    allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='allowedUsersAsUser')
```

This way, if you want a user to be added to the "allowed" list, you can just add them using something like this:

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['file', 'is_public']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.allowed_users.add(request.user)
        self.object.save()
        data = {'status': 'success'}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype =
        response_mimetype(self.request))
        return response
```

Then to make the Admin look nice (admin.py):

```
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('uploaded_by', 'file')

    fields = ('id', 'file', 'uploaded_at', 'extension', 'thumbnail', 'is_public', 'uploaded_by', 'allowed_users')
    filter_horizontal = ('allowed_users',)

    readonly_fields = ('id',)

admin.site.register(Document, DocumentAdmin)
```

Then if you want to check if they're allowed, you can do:

```
if allowed_user in doc.allowed_users:
    print('We have liftoff')
```

Comment: I tried using the ManyToManyField but whenever I uploaded a File, every user account created in the database would be automatically added to the allowed_users without me doing anything and also I wasn't able to access the actual data and modify it.

Comment: Also, when adding uploaded_by and allowed_users to the model I get and error saying that I can't have 2 fields with the same related object.

Comment: I added the `related_name` field to fix the error specified in your second comment, as for your first comment, please be a bit more specific. Can you show me the code of the view? Maybe you're accidentally looping through all users and adding them to `allowed_users`?

Comment: Yes sorry, Im being too vague i think. I updated the post with relevant code. Thanks for the first fix, didn't know about related name. Maybe the CreateView im inheriting from is doing it? not really sure.

Comment: Ok great, now question: So are you saying that when you go through the `DocumentCreate` view, `allowed_users` is populated with ALL the users in the database?

Comment: Im actually not sure why its doing this. Im just guessing it could be that. I mean, i didnt do it at all...im confused

Comment: But is that what it's doing?

Comment: Yes. Every time I upload a file I check in the admin page and the allowed_users Field has all the users.

Comment: I think you may be confused - are the users in the LEFT box or the RIGHT box in the admin field? If they are in the left side that means that they are not yet added to the field (the ones that are added should be on the left)

Comment: Yea I definitely am. Just tired i think. I only have 1 Box, left side. But i can Highlight and "save" the document and I think that adds the users.

Comment: Add a picture of your admin, I think that should get us through this

Comment: [here it is](http://imgur.com/a/Y1CsG). using two screens so it looks weird. So the "highlighted" ones are the added im thinking and the other is not. NOTE: I added those 2 highlighted ones manually

Comment: Also, how/where should I add the allowed users? In the form_valid of "DocumentCreate" or somewhere else...

Comment: So it looks like it's actually working correctly, but the admin has a weird default ManyToMany list. I will update my code to reflect a good Admin view, as well as how to add the Users

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Also nice add with the admin page.thanks again very much

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set content_type on a HttpResponse. So you can do permission handling in your view and serve the file directly from Django:

```
return HttpResponse("Text only, please.", content_type="text/plain")
```

Note: Django isn't a web server. It is recommended to use a web server for serving static files!

The above method might be a good approach if you handle small amounts of data and only incidentally serve data. If you need a robust solution, you need to check permissions in Django and leave the serving of data to the web server.

- Lighthttpd X-Sendfile
- Apache mod_wsgi Internal redirects
- NGNIX X-Accel-Redirect

Have a look at Django file streaming packages: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/file-streaming/

Comment: Im using Apache with mod_wsgi but I dont know if im serving the files through Apache or Django, pretty new to backend and web-dev in general. I actually need to be serving-uploading files pretty constantly so I would be interested in using Apache to serve the files and using django permissions but I cant figure it out right now. How should I proceed?

Comment: So, a little correction. I am serving the static files through Apache already so i'd like to know how to proceed about the django permissions, thanks :)